# Difficulty adding substrings to a string in c

Tags: c, string

I encountered a problem when trying to add substrings to a string in C:
I have a variable that holds data, for example: `"0%, 35.6, 0:1,..."` and I'm trying to add titles to each parameter, for example: `"title1: 0%, title2: 35.6, title3: 0:1,..."`.
I've tried several methods, including using `strtok()`, but with no luck so far. In this case I suspect a casting problem (the variable that holds the data (`Debug` in the code below) is an `UINT8*`), but I don't seem to be able to solve it. Could someone please offer me some directions?

```
 static void SendDebug(UINT8* Debug) {
    char *TempToken;
    char *array[13] = {"some", "titles", "for", "substrings", "here", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."};
    int j=0;
    int i=0;

    sprintf((char *) Debug, "%s,","New_String:");
    strcpy(TempToken, (char *)Debug);

    for (i=0; i<13; i++) {
        strcat((char *)Debug, array[i]);
        while (TempToken[j] != ',' && TempToken[j] != '\0') {
            strcat((char *)Debug, (char *)TempToken[j]);
            j++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When directly add to `TempToken` then why do you require `Debug` ?

Comment: Please post also the variable which you pass to `static void SendDebug(UINT8* Debug)` and the way it is declared and initialized.

Comment: @Alex Lop  Thanks for your response: This is a global variable, which is being parsed in different ways all over the code, that's why I choose to copy it meanwhile (not to harm it by mistake), and why I think it's well passed and declared...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TempToken` is just an uninitialized pointer, using it in any way (except to initialize it) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Declare it either as a character array big enough, or dynamically allocate it.